# Android Sqlite search date via "selection" and "selectionArgs"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I used a code similar to the following code to search the database between two dates :

```
cursor.query(select column from Table where columnDate between '2018-09-20' and '2018-09-23');
```

But now I want to use query `projection`,`selection`and `selcetionArgs`.

How can I update my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
cursor.query("Table" ,
    new String[]{"column"},
    "columnDate BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
    new String[]{"2018-09-20","2018-09-23"},
    null/*Group by if you need*/,
    null/*having if you need*/,
    null/*order by if you need*/);
```